# WPF use one ViewModel for multiple UserControls

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, viewmodel, datacontext

I've searched a lot for an answer for this question, but couldn't quite find an answer.

I have my main `Window` and 4 different `UserControls`. The `Window` is constructed from all 4 `UserControls`.

I have a class which is the `Window`'s `ViewModel`.

I wish to set the `DataContext` of the `Window` and all 4 `UserControls` as the `Window`'s `ViewModel`.

The problem is that writing the class as the control's `DataContext` creates a new instance of the class, hence, I can't use the containers I'm filling.

Any way of doing that?

Comment: Are you using any dependency injection framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContext` gets inherited in WPF.

If you don't set a `DataContext` for the `UserControl`, they will automatically inherit their parent's `DataContext` (the `Window`), and should use your ViewModel directly.